# tool to chart the schema from db2

Tags: sql, charts, db2, uml

are you aware of any `db2` tool or command that, given a database, returns a chart with all tables, fields and (possibly )relationship? If DB2 doesn't provide something like that do you know something else, possibly free/open source, that is not Visual Paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) works well with DB2. I have used it in the past and he output you will get is something like [this](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html).

Comment: Awasame! I will give it a try 'cos it seems what I was looking for!

Comment: It should be. Just make sure you add the db2 driver jars (usually db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar) properly to the Java classpath. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try db2look, an included tool, but it is just a command line that regenerates all DDL.

Also, you can usa IBM Data Studio, an Eclipse based tool that allows you to manage your db2 databases. In the same way, you can do a reverse engineering of the entity relationship diagram.

Both of these tools are free, and part of DB2.

Comment: AngocA!Wow how many tools here!Command Line is also an option I like as Linux user. I will give it a try.